# Request NavigationView refresh from another part of form

Tags: vb.net, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm a newbie with UWP coding. I've got a simple UWP app using VB.NET. Code behind a ContentGrid elsewhere on the same 'form' updates some settings that effect the NavigationView. How can I get the NavigationView to refresh?

I can't seem to reference it from one view to another

XAML snip of Navigation view:

```xml
<winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Main" Name="MainMenu" Tag="" Icon="Home" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage" />
    <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_ContentGrid" Name="Video1" Tag="" Icon="GotoStart" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:ContentGridPage" />
    <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_ContentGrid2" Name="Video2" Tag="\KES\" Icon="Slideshow" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:ContentGridPage2" />
</winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
<winui:NavigationView.PaneFooter>
    <NavigationViewItem Icon="Help" Content="Help" Tag="User"/>
</winui:NavigationView.PaneFooter>
```

VB code behind the form/view to disable menu items in the OnLoaded event, works fine

```vb
For Each topic In navigationView.MenuItems
    strDepends = topic.tag
    bAllowed = Helpers.ContentAllowed(strDepends)
    If Not bAllowed Then topic.IsEnabled = False
Next
```

Code on another view changes the settings, enabling a menu setting but I can't seem to tell the menu to refresh.

I'd like the NavigationView to refresh/repaint/whatever

Comment: Just a small nitpick: You can just use ````topic.IsEnabled = bAllowed````  or the reverse logic if you want.  And now that I look at it more, you can probably just cut out bAllowed unless it's used somewhere else, and set the topic.IsEnabled to the result of Helpers.ContentAllowed().

Comment: To add to @JohnPete22 post, it can be one line `topic.IsEnabled = Helpers.ContentAllowed(topic.tag)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Code on another view changes the settings, enabling a menu setting but I can't seem to tell the menu to refresh.

If we want to make `NavigationView` could update in other view, we pass the NavigationView instance to another view when call Navigate method. I found you have used VB UWP template studio, please refer the following code.

```
Private Sub OnItemInvoked(ByVal sender As WinUI.NavigationView, ByVal args As WinUI.NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs)
    Dim item = navigationView.MenuItems.OfType(Of WinUI.NavigationViewItem).First(Function(menuItem) CStr(menuItem.Content) Is CStr(args.InvokedItem))
    Dim pageType = TryCast(item.GetValue(NavHelper.NavigateToProperty), Type)
    NavigationService.Navigate(pageType, navigationView)
End Sub
```

**Other Page**

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(ByVal e As NavigationEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnNavigatedTo(e)
    Dim nav = TryCast(e.Parameter, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView)

    If nav IsNot Nothing Then

        For Each item As Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem In nav.MenuItems
            // update navigateview's status 
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Being the newbie I am in UWP... I'm confused as to why you'd change the OnNavigatedTo event on the sending page not the page with the NavigationView on it

Comment: OK, I'm really dumb and figured it out now. Thanks so much!